# How to add New Testrun in Testrail with specific testcase instead of include all?

Tags: java, testng, testrail

Below Code is for creating a new test run with include all option in testrail, which select all the test cases from project . If i want to select only a specific set of testcases for my test run,how to add?

```
public static void createSuite() throws IOException, APIException {
        //Login to API
        client = new APIClient("https://swtestacademy.testrail.io");
        client.setUser("canberkakduygu@gmail.com");
        client.setPassword("Qwerty_123");
        //Create Test Run
        Map data = new HashMap();
        data.put("include_all",true);
        data.put("name","Test Run "+System.currentTimeMillis());
        JSONObject c = (JSONObject)client.sendPost("add_run/"+PROJECT_ID,data);
        //Extract Test Run Id
        runId = (Long)c.get("id");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/api/reference/runs.

In order to select a custom test-cases list from a test-suite you should use false for "include_all" and then add an array of custom cases ids.

Example (from the page above):
{
"suite_id": 1,
"name": "This is a new test run",
"assignedto_id": 5,
"refs": "SAN-1, SAN-2",
"include_all": false,
"case_ids": [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]
}

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this(It works for me):

```
List list = Arrays.asList("1919581");
Map<String, Serializable> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("suite_id", 8116);
data.put("name", "Auto add run");
data.put("include_all", false);
data.put("case_ids", (Serializable)list);
JSONObject r = (JSONObject) client.sendPost("add_run/17", data);
```